# How can I refresh Reports Sequentially in Power Bi without manual intervention?

Tags: microsoft-powerbi

I have some Power Bi Reports to refresh which are connected sql server. At present we have scheduled them for the refresh with some idle time in between all.

I would like to put them in a Sequence for auto refresh as: When the current report refresh finishes then the next report refresh should begin automatically.

Is there a way to make that happen?

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the Refresh methods in the Power BI REST API.  Here's the details on refreshing a dataset stored in a group/app workspace, which I assume is your deployment scenario:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/refreshdatasetingroup

There's also more general info in this blog post, including a sample powershell script:

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-data-refresh-apis-in-the-power-bi-service/

Comment: Thanks for sharing these links. Will be trying these methods soon.